# How to detect if user tries to leave tab or page in blazor?

Tags: javascript, c#, .net, blazor

I want to show confirm alert when user tries to leave page or tab. How to do it in blazor c#?

I tried to add javascipt  script with "beforeunreload" event, but I don't know how to do it

```
window.exitTabFunctions = {
    setupExitTabDetection: function () {
        window.addEventListener("beforeunreload", function (event) {
            event.preventDefault();
            event.returnValue = "Sure?";
        });
    }
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. you need to excute that method(`window.exitTabFunctions.setupExitTabDetection`). So you need to excute JS by [`IJSRuntime.InvokeVoidAsync()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/javascript-interoperability/call-javascript-from-dotnet?view=aspnetcore-7.0#component-razor-example-invokevoidasync).
2. That code works in only Firefox and IE. So you need to add `return "Sure?"` below the `event.returnValue = "Sure?";`.

   - ref: [Alert on Browser Back button click or page refresh](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38306510/alert-on-browser-back-button-click-or-page-refresh)

Answer (score 1):

You can set internal or external navigation using NavigationLock component which was introduced in .net 7.

```
<NavigationLock ConfirmExternalNavigation="true" />
```

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.components.routing.navigationlock?view=aspnetcore-7.0